# Сохранение формы ввода данных используя searchModel для поиска записей в бд в yii2

Tags: yii2

Есть форма где пользователь выбирает (факультет,кафедру,группу) с помощью dropDownList, после выводится список студентов в котором пользователь выбирает некоторых из них checkbox и сохраняет.

Я не прошу написать какой либо мне код. Мне нужно хотя какой нибудь наглядный пример, или информация чтобы понять суть выполнения. Долго курил гугл, не смог найти подобного.

Comment: А что сделать-то надо? Что не работает или работает не так?

Comment: никак не могу понять суть как ваще так сделать) мне нужен пример кода, или инфа

Comment: Непонятно как сделать ЧТО? Суть вопроса не ясна, потому что и вопроса-то нет. Понятно, что есть форма для поиска моделей и что она осуществляет поиск. Вопрос заключается в том, что необходимо понять суть выполнения формы?

Comment: обьясню в кратце, по выбранной категории выводится список товаров. В списке есть чекбоксы, выбрая некоторые товары нужно например сохранить их статус.

Comment: воо именно, я не могу вывести список товаров, и еще сохранить это список по чекбоксам

Comment: Сгенерируй CRUD с помощью gii и список товаров будет выводиться. Для чекбоксов можно использовать специальную колонку. Сохранять статус можно с помощью ajax. Например EditableColumn от kartik